# How lo launch test in safari with intern js and selenium grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari, intern, safaridriver

I’m testing with internJs, I want to launch tests in safari browser:

hub machine: Windows 8.1

node machine: Mac Os X El Capitan Version 10.11.6 === Safari version: 10.1.1

In the hub i run:

```
java –jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar –role hub
```

In the node machine i run:

```
java –jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar –role webdriver –hub http://192.168.1.2:4444/grid/register -port 5566
```

Also I installed SafariDriver.safariextz

error:

```
 C:\dev\E2E_Test_WebTv>intern-runner config=tests/intern
Listening on 0.0.0.0:9000
Tunnel started
Suite safari on MAC FAILED
UnknownError: [POST http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session / 
{"desiredCapabilities
":{"selenium-server-standalone":"3.4.0","name":"tests/intern","idle-
timeout":60,
"browserName":"safari","platform":"MAC"}}] Error forwarding the new session 
Empt  y pool of VM for setup Capabilities [{name=tests/intern, 
browserName=safari, idl e-timeout=60, selenium-server-standalone=3.4.0, 
platform=MAC}]  at Server.createSession  
users\Test\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\in
tern\node_modules\leadfoot\Server.js:355:15>
at 
<..\..\Users\Test\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\intern\lib\executors\Run
ner.js:198:23>
at retry  
<..\..\Users\Test\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\intern\lib\util.j
s:818:13>
at 
<..\..\Users\Test\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\intern\node_modules\dojo
 \Promise.ts:393:15>
 at runCallbacks  
  <..\..\Users\Test\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\intern\nod
 e_modules\dojo\Promise.ts:11:11>
 at 
<..\..\Users\Test\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\intern\node_modules\dojo
\Promise.ts:317:4>
at run  
<..\..\Users\Test\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\intern\node_modules
\dojo\Promise.ts:237:7>
at 
<..\..\Users\Test\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\intern\node_modules\dojo
\nextTick.ts:44:3>
at _combinedTickCallback  <internal\process\next_tick.js:73:7>
at process._tickCallback  <internal\process\next_tick.js:104:9>

TOTAL: tested 0 platforms, 0/0 tests failed; fatal error occurred

Error: Run failed due to one or more suite errors
at emitLocalCoverage  
<..\..\Users\Test\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\inter
n\lib\executors\Executor.js:363:18>
at finishSuite  
<..\..\Users\Test\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\intern\lib\
executors\Executor.js:380:15>
at 
<..\..\Users\Test\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\intern\lib\executors\Exe
cutor.js:388:8>
at 
<..\..\Users\Test\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\intern\browser_modules\d
ojo\Promise.ts:393:15>
at runCallbacks  
<..\..\Users\Test\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\intern\bro
wser_modules\dojo\Promise.ts:11:11>
at 
<..\..\Users\Test\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\intern\browser_modules\d
ojo\Promise.ts:317:4>
at run  
<..\..\Users\Test\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\intern\browser_modu
les\dojo\Promise.ts:237:7>
at 
<..\..\Users\Test\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\intern\browser_modules\d
ojo\nextTick.ts:44:3>
at _combinedTickCallback  <internal\process\next_tick.js:73:7>
at process._tickCallback  <internal\process\next_tick.js:104:9>
```